# Could not find generator 'draper:install' rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, draper

Using rails 5 I added the gem

```
gem 'draper', '3.0.0.pre1'
```

then when I call the install generator I get an error

```
Could not find generator 'draper:install'. Maybe you meant 'devise:install', 'config:install' or 'responders:install'
```

Anything Im doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you still need an answer, but try putting the Github repo directly in your Gemfile. Looks like maybe the gem is not up-to-date in RubyGems.

```
gem 'draper', '3.0.0.pre1', github: 'drapergem/draper'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I cant find any answer to this, and to be honest .. I only need a resource specific decorator I ended generating a decorator for each of my models.

```
rails generate resource Article
```

its working like intended.

thanks